Example of nonidentification mixture
Consider a continuous r.v. $X$ with pdf $f$ obeying the following finite mixture model for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k f_k(x) \quad \lambda_k\geq 0, \sum_k\lambda_k=1
$$
Suppose $K=3$. Can you give a simple example to explain why the above mixture model is not identified? Do not refer to the labelling issue in this example.

The likelihood is invariant under permutation of the $K$ component indices, for one thing.

Thanks. Could you please provide an example which does not refer to the labelling? I know that the labelling is an issue, but I would like to see something else in the example.

They usually are identifiable, IMO, and see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2238337 for examples, but an example of a nonidentifiable mixture is a mixture of Bernoulli distributions.  More generally, a mixture of distributions on a finite set is just another distribution on the finite set.

They are NOT identifiable without further restrictions. Indeed, the link you provided list examples of (parametric) restrictions.

Which "they" are you referring to?

What do you assume about the $f_k$??  If nothing, then obviously this is not identified; but in most cases people make specific assumptions about the $f_k$ and there are no problems with identification--not even labeling problems.

Consider this density estimate

It could be an equal mixture of $f_1\sim N(0,1)$, $f_2\sim N(0,3)$ and $f_3\sim N(0,6)$. Or, it could be a mixture where $\lambda_1=2/3$, $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1/6$ and where $f_1$ is this density

and $f_2$ and $f_3$ are both $N(0,6)$.
Restricting $K$ is also important, since you can also think of this density as a mixture of 512 Normal distributions with standard deviation 0.482 --- the graph literally is that (it's a kernel density estimator with Gaussian kernel)
That is, if you don't restrict the components there's no way to distinguish a mixture from a single distribution that just happens to be a more complicated shape. In this example that would be a bit silly, but suppose the distribution looks like

You can write this distribution as a scale mixture of exponentials (and you might in, say, pharmacokinetics) but you can also just regard it as the shape that it is.
